# Что лучше использовать для обновления access token: сервис или поток?

Tags: android, многопоточность, service, oauth

В моем приложение требуется обновлять access token, использую refresh token. Я хочу сделать это в фоне, но не знаю что для этого лучше всего использовать: потоки или сервис. Обновление токена должно работать до тех пор пока пользователь полностью не закрыл приложение

Comment: можно использовать перехватчик для таких целей :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наверное самый оптимальный вариант - использование Service по причине того, что если пользователь свернет приложение - токен будет обновляться и когда он вернется в приложение сможет спокойно продолжить работу.